# How can I tune the SSL connection timeout in haproxy?

Tags: haproxy

It appears the default timeout for SSL handshake is around 2 or 3 seconds, and timed separately from the "connect" timeout setting.

Is there a way to tune this?

Thanks

Comment: Parameter `tune.ssl.timeout` is mentioned in the description of `tls-ticket-keys`but I can't find more documentation about it. You may try to test it.

Comment: What makes you think it's not covered by the `timeout connect` setting?